# how to pretty printed and highlighted structs easily?

Tags: go

I'm writing a lot of little scripts right now to learn go and for better or worse have gotten used to seeing output such as arrays, maps, slices in a nice highlighted, indented, pretty format.

I should maybe use http://golang.org/pkg/go/printer/#example_Fprint
but I'm not exactly sure how to use it nor if it gives me the result I'm looking for...

ex: ruby's pry

[image]

If its a dumb idea for even asking for pretty printed output please explain in brief.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea to me. I also want it!

Comment: I don't think `Fprint` is what you want. Are you reading output in a console? If so, highlighted/colored output requires ANSI color codes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors).

Answer (score 23):

http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/

> %v    the value in a default format.  when printing structs, the plus
>   flag (%+v) adds field names
>
> %#v   a Go-syntax representation of the value

Like so:

```
fmt.Printf("%+v", mystruct)
```

Answer (score 14):

Try [github.com/davecgh/go-spew](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew). It's like `"%#v"`, but has much more prettier and detailed output.

Comment: `spew` does not produce valid Go code, so it not really a replacement for `"%#v"`.